# Accessing an object's 'document' member in IE10 without knowing its type

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I have a javascript function which gets elements by ID, from either the page document, or if the parentObj is passed in, from parentObj.document.

However, in IE10 when I am *not* in compatibility mode, accessing parentObj.document returns 'undefined'. Using the IE developer tools, the parentObj **has** a document member, but it is treated as just a generic object. Different kinds of objects can be passed into the function.

Sample code:

```
function getJSObject(objID, parentObj)
{
    if (parentObj != null)
    {
        return parentObj.document.getElementById(objID);
    }
    return document.getElementById(objID);
}
```

(Not the actual function, this is what I am allowed to post though, to get the idea across.)

Basically, this works in IE10 compatibility mode, and does not work correctly outside of IE10 compatibility mode. What is the correct way to do this?

Edit: Calling code:

```
var selectionPage = objWindows[0].document.forms[sourceForm];
if (selectionPage)
{
    var selectionControl = getJSObject(sourceControlID, selectionPage);
}
```

objWindows is just a simple global level array that keeps track of opened popup windows. sourceForm is the form that called the overall js function, from a popup window.

Comment: Can you add the calling code?

Comment: What is the exception you get?  Also, are both the javascript window and the target window on the same protocol/domain?

Comment: The error message is: "SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'getElementById' of undefined or null reference". Looking in IE's watch variable introspector, `document` exists. However, when parentObj is treated as just a generic `object`, `document` returns as `undefined`.

Comment: It looks like your selecting a form object `[Object, HTMLFormElement]` Which would use `ownerDocument` to get the document and not `document`.

Comment: That ended up being the solution! Thank you. Can you post it as an answer, and I will select it as the correct answer?

Comment: Why not just pass the `document` in explicitly? Your code will clearly be broken on non-legacy IE so why try to preserve the way it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

There are two solutions that would work.  Ideally you would just pass in the `window` object.

```
var selectionPage = objWindows[0];
var formElement = selectionPage.document.forms[sourceForm];
if (formElement)
{
    var selectionControl = getJSObject(sourceControlID, selectionPage);
}
```

**Option 2**

Another solution would be to change `getJSObject` to allow you to pass in a dom element from the window in question.  I would change the function to the following:

```
function getJSObject(objID, objectFromWindow)
{
    if (objectFromWindow != null && !!objectFromWindow.ownerDocument)
    {
        return objectFromWindow.ownerDocument.getElementById(objID);
    }
    return document.getElementById(objID);
}
```

Comment: I had to mangle work code so I wouldn't run afoul of rules here. :P

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this (untested):

```
function getJSObject(objID, parentObj) {
    var parent = parentObj != null) ? parentObj : document;
    var doc;
    while(doc && Object.prototype.toString.call(doc) != "[object HTMLDocument]") {
        doc = doc.parentNode;
    }
    return doc.getElementById(objID);
}
```

Comment: That is interesting, I will try that out.

Comment: Please see the revised code, you should use toString (not typeof) to get the "class" name.